# Xamarin Forms on old Windows Desktops?

Tags: c#, android, wpf, xamarin, telerik

I'm currently starting up a xamarin project to make a LOB app. I can see that we can cover the mobile world but I'm wanting to also create a desktop app.

Where is the split between Xamarin Forms and a wpf application? Can we use Xamarin Forms in a wpf application? Is it more intended that your xamarin forms projects iOS/Android/Store Apps be separate from your wpf/desktop apps? You are just using the shared model/business logic code?

Comment: If you use the standard MVVM pattern then a lot can be shared. Xamarin Forms is designed for mobile, so I think it is intentional that desktop is excluded.

Comment: Desktop is not excluded. You can deploy Windows UWP and MacOS apps from the shared code. There is also a community maintained Xamarin.Forms project for WPF, mentioned by @Sean Kearon below. I would be damn giddy to see Microsoft throw some resources at the community WPF effort.

Answer (score 1):

Xamrin.Forms is optimised for rapid mobile apps development. You cannot really use it for developing WPF/Winforms app.

If app designed well you can share the large amount of business logic/mode code with your desktop apps

Comment: With WinForms getting .NET Core support I wouldn't be surprised to see a WinForms Xamarin.Forms project type appear this year.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Forms 3.0 introduced a preview of support for WPF.  This means you can use Xamarin Forms to produce a desktop application that will run, for example, on Windows 7.

The official documentation is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/wpf

Also see this article:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-wpf-application-using-xamarin-forms/